# UnitestX: ImportError When Importing Modules from Project in Test Files

Tags: python, python-unittest

**Problem:**
I'm using UnitestX as a custom unittest runner for my Python project. While UnitestX is able to find and run the tests, I'm encountering an `ModuleNotFoundError` when it tries to import modules from my project in the test files.

**Context:**
My project structure is organized as follows:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_main.py

3 directories, 7 files
```

**Error:**

```
poetry run unittestx -s tests -p 'test_*.py'

  X ERROR: test_main (unittest.loader._FailedTest.test_main)
Failed to import test module: test_main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/unittest/loader.py", line 382, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/unittest/loader.py", line 325, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/user123/Documents/Playgrounds/lab01-python-playground/tdd-api/tests/test_main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.main import greet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
=======================================================
SUMMARY:   PASSED(0)  FAILED(0)  ERROR(1)  SKIPPED(0)
=======================================================
```

**Expected Behavior:**
UnitestX should be able to successfully import modules from my project, just like when running tests with the built-in `unittest` framework.

**Additional Information:**

- Python version: Python 3.12.0
- Operating system: Darwin (macOS 14.0)
- UnitestX version: v0.1.3

**Note:**
I've checked that the project structure and import statements in my test files are correct. Running the same tests using the built-in `unittest` framework works without any issues.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this `ImportError` would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Tests runs fine using the builtin unittest. If you think the issue is at the unittestx package, then feel free to submit a PR.
https://github.com/fullstack-spiderman/unittestx